# how to fix Unmatched end tag error in IE 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iframe, banner

Web page contains 24 iframes which are refreshed periodically using meta refresh in iframe content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="25">
    <base target="_parent" />
    <link href="/store/Content/Css/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <a class="picture ui-corner-all" 
        href="/store/Store/Details?product=FRUNBLUEJASS">
        <img src="/store/Store/MainImageThumb?product=FRUNBLUEJASS" />
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

In Internet Explorer 10 after page is refreshed by pressing F5, error

```
HTML1509: Unmatched end tag. 
store, line 470 character 5
```

appears in IE developer tools console tab and bottom group text in page appear in single column.
In Chrome page is rendered properly without error. I verified that all tags are matched in page. 
How to fix this ?

jquery, jquery iu, mono/ASP.NET MVC3 are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be a browser problem to me.
Take a look at the cleaned up source code of the site you linked.. you'll end up with an end tag without matching start tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <base href='/store/' />
    *snip*
    <title>Pood</title>
</head>
<body>
    *snip*
        <div id="main">
            *snip*
            <div class='maincontent'>
                *snip*
                <div class='highlightcolor'>
                    *snip*
                </div>  

                <p class='clear_both'>
                    <div class="bottomcategories">
                        *snip*
                    </div>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: left">
                *snip*
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            *snip*
            <div style="text-align: center">
            </div>
        </div>
    ** here **
    </div>
    ** here **
</body>
</html>
```

Anyway when I read about 24 auto-self-refreshing iframes on a single page I have to ask if this is really the best/up-to-date solution. ;-)

Comment: Thank you. In answer html `<div id="container">` is missing. In site this is present and all tags match. Message was caused by nesting div inside p element.  About refreshing 24 images I posted question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807250/how-to-enhance-image-tumbnails-auto-refresh . Can you answer it also ?